# How to seamlesly load different ML models in python?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, onnx, openvino, tflite

Let's say I have my original `.pt` weights and I export them to `ONNX`, `OpenVINO` and `TFLite`. Is there a way of loading these models without needing to write a custom class that checks its type of instance and loads it accordingly?

OpenVINO model loading example:

```py
from openvino.runtime import Core

ie = Core()
classification_model_xml = "model/classification.xml"

model = ie.read_model(model=classification_model_xml)
compiled_model = ie.compile_model(model=model, device_name="CPU")
```

TFlite model loading example:

```py
class TestModel(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(TestModel, self).__init__()

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[1, 10], dtype=tf.float32)])
  def add(self, x):
    '''
    Simple method that accepts single input 'x' and returns 'x' + 4.
    '''
    # Name the output 'result' for convenience.
    return {'result' : x + 4}


SAVED_MODEL_PATH = 'content/saved_models/test_variable'
TFLITE_FILE_PATH = 'content/test_variable.tflite'

# Save the model
module = TestModel()
# You can omit the signatures argument and a default signature name will be
# created with name 'serving_default'.
tf.saved_model.save(
    module, SAVED_MODEL_PATH,
    signatures={'my_signature':module.add.get_concrete_function()})

# Convert the model using TFLiteConverter
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(SAVED_MODEL_PATH)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open(TFLITE_FILE_PATH, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)

# Load the TFLite model in TFLite Interpreter
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(TFLITE_FILE_PATH)
# There is only 1 signature defined in the model,
# so it will return it by default.
# If there are multiple signatures then we can pass the name.
my_signature = interpreter.get_signature_runner()

# my_signature is callable with input as arguments.
output = my_signature(x=tf.constant([1.0], shape=(1,10), dtype=tf.float32))
# 'output' is dictionary with all outputs from the inference.
# In this case we have single output 'result'.
print(output['result'])
```

pt model loading example:

```py
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

Comment: Your exact question is unclear; what *exactly* do you mean by "seamlessly"?

Comment: I updated my question to be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest solution I could find for this, atm, is [Ivy](https://github.com/unifyai/ivy) . However, you have to write your model using their framework agnostic operations and the set of available frameworks are quite limited: `jnp`, `tf`, `np`, `mx`, `torch`

I found a quite good adapter that I will base my own on, [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/2e10909905b1e0e7eb7bac086600fe7ee2c0e6a5/models/common.py#L528)

Answer (score 1):

[OpenVINO Inference Engine API](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/notebooks/002-openvino-api-with-output.html#openvino-api-tutorial) only supports Intermediate Representation (IR) and ONNX models. The [hello_reshape_ssd.py](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/blob/master/samples/python/hello_reshape_ssd/hello_reshape_ssd.py#L28) from the OpenVINO samples shows how to read a model in IR or ONNX format.